# Find the modular exponentiation base yielding a small exponent multiplier that maintains equivalence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $x^c \equiv x^{kc} \pmod n$ where $c$ and $n$ are arbitrary large integers.

Is there a tractable way of choosing $x \in [2 .. n-2]$ such that $k > 1$ is expected to be small with a high probability?

Any pointers are appreciated.

**A little bit of context**

For a given $n$, from modular arithmetic congruence relation, we have the set $S \equiv [0 .. n)$.

By applying modular exponentiation with a given $c$ we can partition this set in subsets $S_x'$ where $x \in S$ is a canonical element (for instance the smallest number in the subset).

Intuitively, to construct iteratively $S_x'$ starting from $x$, its first element, we calculate $x' \in S$  such that $x^c \equiv x' \pmod n$; which then is included in $S_x'$. And from $x'$ we keep doing it until there are no more elements to be added to the set.

More formally $S_x'$ can be defined as: $\{x' \in S | \exists k \geq 0, x^{kc} ≡ x' \pmod n\}$

From this construction we observe that there are two types of sets $S_x'$: 1) ones that form cycles; and 2) ones that converge to $0$, $1$, or $n - 1$.

I am interested in finding, for a given $n$ and $c$, an $x$ such that $S_x'$ not only forms a cycle, but a small one. In other words, $|S_x'|$, the size of $S_x'$, is small. And I am looking at it from the point of view of computational tractability, how easy it could be to find such small cycle, not necessarily the smallest, but small compared to $n$. And what could be the lower bound.

I am sure there is literature and theory related to this kind of constructs but, as I am not a trained mathematician, I am having trouble identifying it. (And I apologize if my attempt to formalize the problem is convoluted, leave a comment and I can try to improve it.)